# object reference after Serialization and De-Serialization

Tags: c#-4.0

Why after  De-Serialization the object reference not same as it was before serilization.

ok let me Explain this

I am Having  a String

string test = "TestString";

Now I do Serilization

```
                  DataContractJsonSerializer _DataContractJsonSerializer
          = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));

                       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            _DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(ms, test);
            var jsonString = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Now I do DeSerilization from jsonstring into actual value

```
        MemoryStream ms1 =
            new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
            string DeseriliaedStrring = serializer.ReadObject(ms1) as string;
```

here in DeseriliaedStrring i got the actual value but if i check there reference they are not equal

```
bool isReferenceEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(DeseriliaedStrring, test);
```

Comment: They're not supposed to reference the same object, one is the source and others (deserialised) are facsimiles, they are comparable, but not one in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you serialize and deserialize an object, the deserialization will create an instance base on the serialized data. This is of course not the same instance as the original one, that seems fairly logical. After all, you have the following process:

- You have an object instance
- You create a string instance that is a representation of that object instance
- You create an object instance based on the serialized data in the string

If you take into consideration that the original instance might have mutated, that the deserialization can happen in another process, even in another machine, it becomes quite clear that deserialization could not possibly return the original instance.

In this particular case, when the object is a `String`, you could imagine that the string interning would make the system reuse the old instance (if the deserialization happened within the same AppDomain). But that would probably* require `DataContractJsonSerializer` to be aware of this, which would make it unnecessarily complex.

<sub>*) I am actually not quite sure of exactly *what* part of the system that takes care of string interning.</sub>

Comment: what to do if i needed the same refernce after deserilization, is there is any way to do this

Comment: @slash: within an AppDomain there is always a way, it is more a matter of how much work and memory you are willing to sacrifice. The more important question is: *why*?

Answer (score 2):

Serialization creates copies of the object's values. Deserialization creates a completely new instance with the copied values.

Edit in response to your comment below: Deserialization doesn't call a constructor. If this is a problem, then override with `ISerializable`. This will serialise based on a call to `ISerializable.GetObjectData` and then call a particular constructor with `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext` fields.

Comment: ok this example is related to string but if i do this serilization and deserilization for any custom class... the constructure must be called if i deserilizad the class becoze as u said i creates the new instance....

Comment: @slash shogde Deserialization doesn't call the default constructor. The object is being created directly from the bytestream.

Comment: Thankyou very much,ur answer is very right,i have incremented the point only ,as becoz already i check the above answer.. plz dont mind

Comment: Well is there is a way to get the same reference